# Binning by Subgroup in R

Tags: r, grouping, binning

I have a dataframe with Markets, Retailers and Sales.  I need to bin the Retailers within each Market into 5 quantiles.

Example:

[image: Grouped]

```
dataframe <- structure(list(Market = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), Retailer = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Sales = c(5, 10, 25, 5, 10, 25), Quantile = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: You could use `tapply` with FUN = `cut` and breaks = quantile(x, probs=seq(0,1,1/5)). You should `dput` your data though.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Also show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is using `group_by` and `ntile` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe %>%
  group_by(Market) %>%
  mutate(Quantile = ntile(Sales, 4))
# A tibble: 150 x 4
# Groups:   Market [3]
   Market Retailer Sales Quantile
    <int>    <int> <dbl>    <int>
 1      1        1 16804        1
 2      1        2 80752        4
 3      1        3 38494        2
 4      1        4 32773        2
 5      1        5 60210        3
# … with 145 more rows
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(3)
dataframe <- data.frame(Market = rep(1:3, each = 50), 
                        Retailer = rep(1:50, times = 3), 
                        Sales = round(runif(150,0,100000),0))
```